# Access model attributes inside relationship

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Here is an example of my relationship

```
$fillable = ['bicycle_id'];
public function mouse()
{
    return $this
        ->hasOneThrough(Mouse::class, House::class, 'user_id', 'id', 'id', 'mouse_id')
        ->whereHas('bicycles', function (Builder $query) {
            return $query->where('bicycles.id', '=', $this->bicycle_id);
        });
}
```

I can't access my model attributes (e.g. `$this->bicycle_id`) when I load relationship using `with` or `load` - it returns `null` (working Ok when I retrieve my model without relationship and then access it like `$user->mouse` btw)

As I understand model attributes is not loaded yet when I try to access them while eager loading. Is there any workaround?

Comment: have your tried : $query->whereColumn('bicycles.id', '=', 'myModelTableName. bicycle_id'); ?

Comment: @OMR There is an error when I try to fetch model - `Illuminate/Database/QueryException with message 'SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'users.bicycle_id' in 'where clause'`

Comment: You cant do this in laravel eloquent,you should use joins.